# How Can I Make Args On Telegram Python Bot That Filters A Words?

Tags: python

I Want To Make My Bot That Can Filters Args

Example : /ping example.com{IFS};

I want to block {IFS};

If Someone Run With That, Bot Will Not Respons.

Please Help Me

```
if sender in authorized_senders:

  args=text.split()

  command = args[0]
  if command == '/ping':
        host = str(args[1])
        output=os.popen("ping -c1 "+host).read()
        bot.sendMessage(chat_id, output)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don’t put user input into shell commands (`/ping example.com; cat /etc/passwd; rm -rf *` would be bad too). The [`subprocess` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) allows you to run programs like `ping` directly, and you still have to be extremely careful about how those programs will interpret their arguments. `--` will stop arguments that follow it from being interpreted as options for many programs, at least.

This is a much safer start:

```
output = subprocess.check_output(["ping", "-c1", "--", host])
```

It’s also a good idea to validate the format of `host` anyway, e.g. with a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html).

```
if not re.fullmatch(r"[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)*", output, re.ASCII):
    # don't run the command
```

(that one is for ASCII alphanumerics or hyphens separated by dots, which doesn’t cover plain IPv6 addresses, note.)